# Working with the events of various controls

Tags: vb.net, events, controls

I want to use the following snippit.

```
    For Each x As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf x Is CustomControl Then
            SomeAction( x.CustomEventofCustomControl)
        End If
    Next
```

The problem here is that not all controls have event CustomEventofCustomControl, so the complier shrieks. How do I get around this.

ps: Any ideas for a better title?

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be use some marker interface like IHasWhateverEvent (tell me which one and I'll compose a better name, of course!). That interface has no members, since it's a marker one.

You make any of your custom controls having that event implement this blank interface, then you do that:

```
For Each x As Control In Me.Controls
        If x Is IHasWhateverEvent Then
            SomeAction(((IHasWhateverEvent)x).CustomEventofCustomControl)
        End If
Next
```

Or if you can, just add an event in your interface so when you cast some control to IHasWhateverEvent, you'll have access to the event itself.

Comment: You might have to add the Event to the interface and do SomeAction(ctype(x, IHasWhateverEvent).CustomEventofCustomControl), I think the compiler will still tell you that CustomEventofCustomControl is not a member of Control

Comment: That's what's I'm suggesting :D By the way, you're right about second statement: I forgot a cast. I updated the sample code.

Comment: I dont really understand your answer. You may be right, I dont know. At any rate, the mention of casting got my on the right track. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What solved the problem for me:

```
 For Each x As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf x Is CustomControl Then
            SomeAction( CType(x, CustomControl).CustomEventofCustomControl)
        End If
    Next
```